# SHCreateStreamOnFile returns invalid argument when passing STGM_DELETEONRELEASE

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I am calling

```
SHCreateStreamOnFile(stTempFile, 
    STGM_CREATE | STGM_READWRITE | STGM_DELETEONRELEASE, &stream)
```

it returns invalid argument.

I really need this functionality because I am using this file as temporary storage for drag and drop. Help?

Comment: `SHCreateStreamOnFile` is [not supported beyond Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759864(v=vs.85).aspx), depending on your OS you might try `SHCreateStreamOnFileEx` instead.

Comment: Roger Rowland comment is 100% accurate, STGM_ DELETEONRELEASE is not supported by SHCreateStreamOnFile. Function dont lie you. :-)

Comment: I did try using SHCreateStreamOnFileEx. It works. Sort of. It creates a stream but the file never gets deleted.